# Counting button presses javafx

Tags: button, javafx, label, scene

I am new to javaFX, i need to print the amount of times i have pressed a button in javaFX on a label. So the Scene consists of a a button and a label and everytime i press the button the number should go up on the label. I dont seem to get i right. Anyone got some tips?

This is what i have!
public class fråga4 extends Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tryck här");
    primaryStage.setWidth(300);
    primaryStage.setHeight(100);

    VBox root = new VBox();
    Button btn = new Button("Tryck här!");
    Label lbl = new Label();

    btn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        btn.getOnMouseClicked();
            });


    root.getChildren().addAll(btn,lbl);
    Scene scene = new Scene (root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

}

Comment: So increment a variable and update the label's text with that new value (convert the integer into a string) for each click.

Comment: time for working through a tutorial on java language basics ..

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable to count the button clicks , and this is an example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
primaryStage.setTitle("Tryck här");
primaryStage.setWidth(300);
primaryStage.setHeight(100);

VBox root = new VBox();
Button btn = new Button("Tryck här!");
Label lbl = new Label();

// this is the variable
int i = 0 ;

btn.setOnAction(e -> {
    i++ ;
    System.out.println(""+i) ;
    btn.getOnMouseClicked();
        });


root.getChildren().addAll(btn,lbl);
Scene scene = new Scene (root);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

}

   }
```